# IOS isEqualToString Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsfilemanager

The following example program outputs the same, but the program does not work correctly.

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                   enumeratorAtPath:kDocdir];

for (NSString *pathi in directoryEnumerator)
{
   NSString *fileName_Manager = [pathi lastPathComponent];
   NSLog(@"fileName_Manager = %@",fileName_Manager);

   Artist *name_Databse =  [self.fetchedResultsController
                               objectAtIndexPath:IndexPath];
   NSLog(@"name_Databse     = %@",name_Databse.name);



   if ([fileName_Manager isEqualToString:name_Databse.name]) {
       NSLog(@"Same Name");
   }else{
       NSLog(@"Different Name");
   }

}
```

Outputs:

```
2013-04-25 15:37:43.256 Player[36436:907] fileName_Manager = alizée - mèxico - final j'en
2013-04-25 15:37:43.272 Player[36436:907] name_Databse     = alizée - mèxico - final j'en
2013-04-25 15:37:44.107 Player[36436:907] Different Name
```

does not work correctly when special characters in names.  Why is this happening?
Thanks ...

have the same problem here:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",[pathi lastPathComponent]];
```

How do I make an edit here?

Comment: you might have spaces inside your strings, try to remove the extra spaces or new-line characters

Comment: Please consider my highly upvoted answer for a check-mark!

Answer (score 12):

The documentation for `isEqualToString:` suggests you might have a problem:

> The comparison uses the canonical representation of strings, which for
>   a particular string is the length of the string plus the Unicode
>   characters that make up the string. When this method compares two
>   strings, if the individual Unicodes are the same, then the strings are
>   equal, regardless of the backing store. “Literal” when applied to
>   string comparison means that various Unicode decomposition rules are
>   not applied and Unicode characters are individually compared. **So,
>   for instance, “Ö” represented as the composed character sequence “O”
>   and umlaut would not compare equal to “Ö” represented as one Unicode
>   character**.

Try using `(NSOrderedSame == [string1 localizedCompare:string2])`

Also, if you haven't already, look into the Apple sample code '**International Mountains**' which deals with numerous localization issues.

Comment: thank you very much. isEqualToStrings worked properly. have the same problem here: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",[pathi lastPathComponent]];  How do I make an edit here?

Comment: @user2041226 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE [cd] %@",[pathi lastPathComponent]]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried converting both strings to UTF-8 and then do the comparison? I don't know if that works, it's just an idea.